# how to check the convergence of the following series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was having a hard time grasping the concept of convergence and how to check convergence for the following series:
$$
a_n= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}.
$$

Comment: There are $n$ terms. The sum is between $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n-1}}$ and $\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$. Squeeze.

Comment: Is it the sequence $\{a_n\}$ you want to check convergence for, or is it some series involving $a_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every term of the sum is between $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$.

Since there are $n$ terms, $a_n$ is between $1-\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $1$, so $a_n\to 1$.

Comment: Did you notice the beauty of $a_n=\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},n^2+n\right)-\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},n^2+2 n\right)$ ?